# Video.js not supporting youtube in firefox on osx

Tags: javascript, macos, youtube, video.js

I am using video.js to get YouTube videos through their YouTube plugin, everything works just fine but in Firefox MAC OSX it won't work, is that a bug for videojs or its just a problem of mine?

Here is the code I'm using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>

<link href="../css/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6/video.js"></script>


</head>
<body> <video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360">
  </video>
<script src="../js/youtube.js"></script>
  <script>
  videojs('vid1', { "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ" }).ready(function() {
    // Cue a video using ended event
    // Most video.js events are supported
    this.one('ended', function() {
      this.src('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE');
      this.play();
    });
  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The VideoJS Youtube Plugin does not yet support VideoJS v4.6.0. The plugin's author has stated that support will be added in an the next update, as seen in the following Github issue: [Support for 4.6.0](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/issues/115)

Comment: That ticket has been closed however it appears that this problem still exists. ```"VIDEOJS:" "ERROR:" "(CODE:0 MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM)" "" Object { isTrusted: true, message: "" }``` . Any info on how to resolve this?